# Syntax Help Required (use of a string variable)

Tags: xcode, string, stringwithformat

I'm doing something slightly or monumentally wrong.

I want to swap a UIColour for a programmable variable, for example:

```
NSString *DataColourTitle = @"greenColor";
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", DataColourTitle]]];
```

I'm getting an Expected Identifier error at the NSString part and haven't worked out the formatting required to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for calling a class method of UIColor would be `[UIColor <#some selector#>]` where <#some selector#> is an identifier such as `greenColor`, not a string.  The selector that it expects is a reference to code that can return a UIColor object, whereas `@"greenColor"` is just a static, literal string of bytes wrapped up as a NSString object.

Try something like:

```
SEL green = NSSelectorFromString(@"greenColor");
UIColor *color = [UIColor performSelector:green];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: color];
```

Comment: Brilliant - changed @"greenColor" to my variable in the NSSelectorFromString and worked first time. Many thanks.